# What comes next in this sequence?

Tags: letter-sequence

Examine the following sequence:

O, T, T, F, F, S, S, E, ?

Can you determine what comes next?

Comment: Too easy :-)  This is a very common riddle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> N

Explanation:

> Each letter is the first letter of English counting numbers.
>  **O**ne, **T**wo, **T**hree, **F**our, **F**ive, **S**ix, **S**even, **E**ight, **N**ine