# Mission: Impossible 1

Tags: cipher

Ethan Hunt is alerted by the IMF. They want him to intercept a courier that is working for the super villains Matt Fillimore and Caro Bassanara. Ethan Hunt receives the following cipher from the IMF:

```
  8901  6892  31  389987688  782  154  6119
```

What is the code-name of the courier?
Where should Ethan intercept the courier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good, it is nice to see some new twist on an old puzzle. 
As a first hint: the underlying code has also been used in the puzzle 
"[What comes next in this sequence?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3751/what-comes-next-in-this-sequence)" posted by Gilles in November 2014. 
It also shows up in some books of Martin Gardner published in the 1960s.

Now the answer to the Mission Impossible puzzle is:

> The code-name of the courier is **Enzo**.
>   Ethan Hunt should intercept the courier in **Tennessee**.

Motivation of answer:

> 0=Z(ero), 1=O(ne), 2=T(wo), 3=T(hree), 4=F(our), 5=F(ive), 6=S(ix), etc.

Under this substitution code, the message to Ethan becomes

```
 8901  6892  31  389987688  782  154  6119    
 ENZO  SENT  TO  TENNESSEE. SET  OFF  SOON!
```