# Find the missing letter?

Tags: letter-sequence

Find the missing letter in this puzzle.
*Which letter will come at first place?*

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What comes next in this sequence?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3751/what-comes-next-in-this-sequence)

Comment: @Len This one is arguably better since it's a larger sample size with a graphic. For the other post, you could find for example a famous quote starting with those letters. I don't really know what goes into deciding which should be the main one so I ended up just answering instead of voting to close.

Comment: @Quark - For the other post, I am going by the OP's intent which is the same sequence. Usually the second post is called the duplicate unless it is perhaps much better but I do not know of such an example.  There are differing perspectives on exactly what is a duplicate and the decision requires 5 votes.  You are welcome to cast your vote by visiting the review queue.

Comment: The answer to both are the same, but that is known only after solving the puzzle. The Presentation looks Sufficiently Different. Hence marking as "Not Duplicate". ((Not all puzzles whose core is the same can be marked as Duplicates))

Comment: The thing that made this stand out for me was the repeated pattern - at first glance, the second half is identical to the first, suggesting a different answer than the correct one. The linked question has a similar premise and answer, but I think they're distinct enough to leave them both be.

Comment: The different thicknesses of the lines are an unintended red herring.

Comment: @Quark _This one is arguably better since it's a larger sample size with a graphic._ I'd argue that using a picture where text would suffice isn't necessarily better... leaves out the visually impaired for whom screen readers could help read the text, and also anyone who's on a network that blocks the common image sites (somewhat common on workplace networks).

Comment: @glibdud You make a good point, I guess it would only be better if the positioning and extra characters made a difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is:

> O, the boxes represent the first letters of "one, two, three, four, five, six" etc.

Answer (score 12):

I think the other answers about it being:

> O

are correct, but at the same time there is zero context for the puzzle. You're just asking me to spot a pattern. As such, I propose that the answer could just as easily be:

> E

Why?

> -Treat each column as an individual vertical sequence
> -The letters of each column repeat vertically
> -E.g. from right-most column to left-most column, bottom to top:
> T-F-T-F
> N-F-N-F
> E-T-E-T
> S-T-S-T
> S-E-S-?

My alternative answer is:

> E

Comment: This looks valid to me, I had spotted this pattern before checking the other answers.

Comment: I wonder if any patterns like this can be found in the first letters of numbers further up the scale...

Comment: Definitely a good point. (And I never noticed that repeating pattern before in the first twenty numbers) I wonder if my answer could really be considered the correct one.

Comment: +1, correct answer is `0` , alternative answer is just to confuse with similar pattern.

Comment: @himanshu define "correct". Any answer that follows a pattern is correct. Just because it's not the answer the asker had in mind doesn't make it less correct.

Comment: @theyetiman, it is in my mind, actually that pattern I made like that only to confuse.

Comment: @Himanshu then by adding it on purpose, you added another correct answer on purpose. You didn't specify that the sequence should go left-to-right, top-to-bottom. You didn't specify any rules at all.

Answer (score 3):

> O (denoting One)

Others in the puzzle

> `O(1) T(2) T(3) F(4) F(5)
>   S(6) S(7) E(8) N(9) T(10)
>   E(11) T(12) T(13) F(14) F(15)
>   S(16) S(17) E(18) N(19) T(20)`